# STM32 debugging issue

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, truestudio, stm32cubeide

I am using a Nucleo F303RE board. And whenever I try to debug in STM32cubemxIDE. It always shows an error for failed to start GDB error. I have attached the screenshot

I have updated the ST-Link firmware and also checked my device manager.

I have also tried disabling my windows defender.

I have also tried to change the frequency, interface, auto-connect under Debug Configuration.

Would be great if someone could help me out. I am stuck with an important demo at work.

I also tried it on Atollic TrueStudio but still no luck.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxaId.png)

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7phKf.png)

Detailed error on Atollic TrueStudio:
STMicroelectronics ST-LINK GDB server. Version 5.1.0
Copyright (c) 2018, STMicroelectronics. All rights reserved.

Starting server with the following options:
Persistent Mode            : Disabled
Logging Level              : 1
Listen Port Number         : 61234
Status Refresh Delay       : 15s
Verbose Mode               : Disabled
SWD Debug                  : Enabled

Target no device found

Error in initializing ST-LINK device.
Reason: No device found on target.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is: *No device found on target*. This Means the debugger is working but it can't connect to the microcontroller.

> The problem may be one of these:

- The **connection** between the debugger and the controller. Check them first.
- The **serial wire debugger is disabled** (I strongly think that this is the problem).
  when you create a new project in CubeMX or CubeIDE the serial wire debugger by default is disabled (I expect that you burn the code for only one time :) ). So you **MUST erase the flash** using stlink utility or such a tool. And **enable the serial wire debugger** from the CubeMX in category SYS.

Comment: Thank you so much for logically explaining what the problem is. I will take your advice and try to figure out. I am currently finding the tool which will let me erase the flash. ST-Link Utility does let me update the firmware though :)